# Em que situações devo alocar um vector dinamicamente em C++?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Estou mexendo em um código de um framework para meu trabalho. Em uma das funções, ele aloca dinamicamente um `std::vector`, faz uma cópia de cada nó que o objeto possui e o retorna para o usuário:

```c++
std::vector<Node> *Tree::getAllNodes() {
    std::vector<Node> *n, *aux;
    n = new vector<Node>();
    mut.lock();
    for (int i = 0; i < subnodes.size(); ++i) {
        aux = subnodes[i]->GetNodes();
        n->insert(n->end(), aux->begin(), aux->end());
    }
    mut.unlock();
    return n;
}
```

Ou seja, fica a cargo do usuário liquidar essa memória depois.

Mas, não sei se é realmente necessário alocar essa memória dinamicamente, já que o `vector` cuida disso para gente, por debaixo dos panos, correto?

Um dos motivos que encontro é que é mais barato retornar apenas o ponteiro do que a cópia do vetor, quando temos muitos dados. Se não o alocássemos dinamicamente, teríamos que retornar uma cópia e, por serem muitos dados, teria maior custo.

**Perguntas:**

1. Esse é realmente um caso que deveríamos alocar o `vector` dinamicamente?
2. Nos demais casos, quando temos poucos dados e/ou poucas chamadas a essa função, é desnecessário fazer essa alocação dinâmica? Afinal, o gerenciamento de memória fica mais simples.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Não posso ver nenhuma vantagem real em alocar um `std::vector` dinamicamente. Mas deve-se ter cuidado ao retornar um vetor como resultado de uma função. Mesmo ele sendo pequeno (tipicamente 12 bytes em sistemas 32-bit) seu construtor de cópia é lento.

- Se possível, permita que o compilador aplique as otimizações de retorno. Nelas o objeto a ser retornado é construído diretamente na variável de destino dele depois da chamada da função. São duas modalidades possíveis (12.8/31):

  - **NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization)**: Quando você cria uma variável dentro da função cujo tipo é o tipo de retorno da função e em todos os pontos de retorno, você retorna essa variável. Exemplo:

    ```cpp
    // Otimização de valor nomeado:
    //  Todos os returns devem retornar a mesma variável local.
    std::vector<int> func_nrvo() {
        std::vector<int> result;
        // execute algo aqui e adicione elementos ao vetor
        return result;
    }

    std::vector<int> result = func_nrvo();
    ```
  - **RVO (Return Value Optimization)**: Quando você retorna um objeto construído no próprio ponto de retorno, ou seja: um temporário (que seja exatamente do tipo da função). Exemplo:

    ```cpp
    // Otimização de valor não nomeado:
    //  Todos os returns devem ser um objeto temporário do tipo de retorno.
    std::vector<int> func_rvo() {
        return std::vector<int>(5, 0);
    }

    std::vector<int> result = func_rvo();
    ```
- Se não for possível aplicar essas otimizações (sugiro reescrever de forma que a função fique como em um desses exemplos), então resta duas opções: **mover** ou **copiar** o objeto, sendo a primeira bastante leve e a segunda muito custosa. Infelizmente não existe o conceito de **mover** no C++03 e se você não pode utilizar o C++11 terá que usar de outros meios para evitar a cópia, como usar um argumento de referência para retornar:

  ```cpp
  void func_ref(std::vector<int>& vec) {
      vec.clear();
      vec.push_back(1);
  }

  std::vector<int> vec;
  func_ref(vec);
  ```
- Se você usa um compilador que suporta o C++11:

  O vetor nesse caso tem um construtor que pode mover o objeto. Então retornar o vetor por uma função é bastante leve e você não precisa se preocupar. Nos casos em que a otimização de retorno de valor não se aplicar, mas se você retornar uma variável local, o resultado será movido automaticamente. Mas você pode forçar a ação de mover usando o [`std::move`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) se a situação for diferente.

  ```cpp
  std::vector<int> func1() {
      return std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
  }

  std::vector<int> func2() {
      std::vector<int> a, b;
      if (rand() % 2)
          return a;
      else
          return b;

      // Otimização não se aplica. Estamos retornando variáveis diferentes.
      // Mas ainda estamos retornando variáveis, mover é implícito.
  }

  std::vector<int> func3() {
      std::vector<int> a, b;
      return (rand() % 2) ? std::move(a) ? std::move(b);
      // Otimização não se aplica. Estamos retornando variáveis diferentes.
      // Mas note que não estamos retornando variáveis, e sim uma estrutura
      // mais complexa (a condicional ternária). Nesse caso precisa forçar o move.
  }

  std::vector<int> vec1 = func1(); // Resultado construído diretamente em vec1
  std::vector<int> vec2 = func2(); // Resultado movido para vec2
  std::vector<int> vec3 = func3(); // Resultado movido para vec3
  ```

## Nota:

No código da sua função vejo que você usa uma mutex. Repare que a chamada da função `insert` no vector pode falhar e lançar a exceção `std::bad_alloc` em caso de falta de memória. Se isso acontecer sua função será encerrada sem liberar a mutex. Um deadlock aguardando para surgir!

O ideal é usar uma classe cujo construtor trave a mutex e o destrutor a destrave, como o [`std::lock_guard`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard). Assim mesmo no caso de uma exceção a mutex será liberada pois o destrutor das variáveis locais sempre é chamado.

## Em caso de dúvida...

As regras que regem exatamente qual tipo de construtor chamar, quando e quais otimizações podem ser feitas em cada caso são bastante complexas e analisar um código se baseando apenas em seus "instintos" pode ser arriscado. Quando defronte a situações como essa uma atitude é confiar em seu compilador para lhe dizer o que está acontecendo. Em vez de um vetor, use uma classe "cobaia" para ver através do código. Exemplo:

```cpp
struct Cobaia {
    Cobaia() {cout << "  Cobaia()" << endl;}
    ~Cobaia() {cout << "  ~Cobaia()" << endl;}
    Cobaia(const Cobaia&) {cout << "  Cobaia(const Cobaia&)" << endl;}
    Cobaia(Cobaia&&) {cout << "  Cobaia(Cobaia&&)" << endl;} // apenas C++11
};

volatile bool cond = true; // volatile para não otimizar

Cobaia func1() { Cobaia r; return r; }
Cobaia func2() { return Cobaia(); }
Cobaia func3() { Cobaia a, b; if (cond) return a; else return b; }
Cobaia func4() { Cobaia a, b; return cond ? a : b; }
Cobaia func5() { Cobaia a, b; return std::move(cond ? a : b); } // apenas C++11

int main() {
    cout << "func1:" << endl; Cobaia c1 = func1();
    cout << "func2:" << endl; Cobaia c2 = func2();
    cout << "func3:" << endl; Cobaia c3 = func3();
    cout << "func4:" << endl; Cobaia c4 = func4();
    cout << "func5:" << endl; Cobaia c5 = func5(); // apenas C++11
    cout << "fim:" << endl;
}
```

Aqui o resultado desse programa (compilado com GCC 4.8.1 em modo C++11, comentários meus):

```cpp
func1:
  Cobaia() // Otimização acontecendo. Tudo acontece como se 'c1' estivesse dentro de func1
func2:
  Cobaia() // Otimização acontecendo. Tudo acontece como se 'c2' estivesse dentro de func2
func3:
  Cobaia() // Construção do local a
  Cobaia() // Construção do local b
  Cobaia(Cobaia&&) // Mover a ou b para c3
  ~Cobaia() // Construção do local b
  ~Cobaia() // Construção do local a
func4:
  Cobaia() // Construção do local a
  Cobaia() // Construção do local b
  Cobaia(const Cobaia&) // Copiar a ou b para c4
  ~Cobaia() // Construção do local b
  ~Cobaia() // Construção do local a
func5:
  Cobaia() // Construção do local a
  Cobaia() // Construção do local b
  Cobaia(Cobaia&&) // Mover a ou b para c5
  ~Cobaia() // Construção do local b
  ~Cobaia() // Construção do local a
fim:
  ~Cobaia() // Destruir c5
  ~Cobaia() // Destruir c4
  ~Cobaia() // Destruir c3
  ~Cobaia() // Destruir c2
  ~Cobaia() // Destruir c1
```

Observe a diferença entre `func3`, `func4` e `func5`. É um exemplo claro do quão obscuras essas regras podem ser. Em `func3` o retorno é uma variável local, logo possui um endereço fixo de onde os dados podem ser **movidos**. No caso de `func4` a expressão de retorno é um temporário, logo é esperado que seu valor vá ser destruído logo antes de efetivamente retornar da função. Dessa forma o compilador precisa primeiro **copiar** o resultado para o endereço de retorno antes de continuar. Na `func5` uso o [`std::move`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) para converter a expressão em um `Cobaia&&` que pode ser **movido**.

Se você executar o mesmo código em C++03 verá que as últimas realizam cópias já que não existe o conceito de mover um objeto.

Para doses extras de diversão, acrescente a *flag* `-fno-elide-constructors` no GCC. Ela desliga todas essas otimizações e você poderá ver todas e cada uma das cópias acontecendo. Um exercício: determinar o motivo de cada uma.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e pela observação do `mutex`, Guilherme. Não sabia desse nuance entre C++03 e C++11. Você poderia me fornecer alguma referência para essas otimizações de valor nomeado e não-nomeado? Gostaria de ler um pouco sobre o assunto. Uma vantagem de sempre passar por referência é que fica garantido que teremos o comportamento desejado, para qualquer versão do C++.

Comment: Não encontrei uma boa referencia em português, mas aqui tem uma página da wikipédia inglesa: [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). Eu particularmente não gosto de retornar por um parametro. Faz o uso da função ficar um pouco não intuitivo.

Comment: Isso é verdade. Uma forma de deixar um pouco menos ambíguo é usar a sintaxe do [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Reference_Arguments#Reference_Arguments). Parâmetros de entrada são `const T& input` e parâmetros de saída são `T* output`. Talvez se também usar algum prefixo.

Comment: Uma pequena dica: independente da forma utilizada para retornar / gerar o vetor, como ele sabe de antemão quantos elementos vai precisar, é vantajoso invocar o reserve do vetor para evitar múltiplas alocações durante os pushs.

Comment: @Math não me pergunte como isso paçou. Mas sim, aproveitei para reestruturar uma parte. Obrigado!

Comment: Estava relendo hoje. Taí uma resposta que definitivamente seria ótima de se ter no SO em inglês. Não me lembro de ter encontrado algo tão bem detalhado por lá. E caramba, 3 anos ontem!

Answer (score 2):

Em certos casos poderá ser vantajoso/necessário criar o vector dinamicamente:

Situação 1:
Tens um processo multithreaded e tens uma heap propria para cada thread (por motivos de performance), neste caso crias o vector na respectiva heap da thread.

Situação 2:
Utilizas um custom allocator, se este não for **static** não tens possibilidade de declarar algo do tipo:

```
vector<unsigned int, my_allocator<unsigned int>> vVector;
```

porque o teu my_allocator ainda não "existe" e ao declarares o vector ele automaticamente necessita de um allocator, para fazer a sua inicialização.