# Como concatenar o nome de uma variável em C++?

Tags: array, c++, variáveis

É possível concatenar o nome de uma variável em C++? Algo como isso:

```
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
   int casa = 10;
   string a = "ca";
   string b = "sa";
 cout << a+b << endl;

/*** console imprime int casa ***/
 /*** result console: 10 ***/

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não. São variáveis diferentes. Talvez você consiga efeito semelhante utilizando ponteiros, mas não exatamente dessa forma.

Comment: Obrigado
considerando por uma nova perspectiva, olhe isso:
for (int i = 1; int < 100, int++)
    cout << int(i) << endl;

Comment: O que você quer nem faz sentido, diga o que deseja, tem outra solução para isto sem fazer o que está pedindo.

Comment: Eu tenho 300 variáveis tipo int. E quero imprimir uma lista dela, sem precisar digitar cout << my_int1... cout << my_int2    300 vezes....

Comment: Dê uma estudada em array, pode ser que possa ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

Você quer usar um *array*, ou em C++ provavelmente um `vector` funcionará melhor, assim você tem a variável dividida em duas partes, uma variável mais ampla que contém toda uma coleção de outras variáveis e terá um nome como está acostumado. Aí cada um dos elementos dentro dessa lista serão variáveis individuais que serão acessadas pelo seu índice, ou seja, um número inteiro sequencial que indica qual posição da coleção que está se referindo.

Falei genericamente sobre isso em [Diferença entre std::list, std::vector e std::array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101) mostrando inclusive outras formas de obter uma coleação semelhante. Tem também como usar o *array* de C, mas não aconselho em C++, faz de conta que isso não existe, até ter conhecimentos avançados e aí pode ser que um dia ele seja útil.

Dei respostas com exemplos do seu uso em várias perguntas:

- [Como utilizar a classe vector do C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118299/101)
- [Manipulação de Vectors em C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112029/101)
- [Diferença das declarações de arrays C/C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202826/101)
- [Como inserir dinamicamente em um std::array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164156/101)
- [Passando array como parâmetro de uma função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320154/101)
- [Como adicionar elementos na posição "x" de um std::vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110841/101)
- [Tipo de retorno variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215352/101)
- [Como usar o vector para armazenar uma classe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120231/101)
- [Contar elementos numa gama de valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104151/101)

E tem outras respostas boas para entender melhor sua utilização:

- [Em que situações devo alocar um vector dinamicamente em C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/379/101)
- [C++ (básico): for, referências e sintaxe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/296790/101)
- [Alguém sabe como inserir nomes em ordem alfabética em um vetor c++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6966/101)
- [Como funciona utilizar um vector do tipo struct ? (C++)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250399/101)

Se precisasse de um índice não inteiro e/ou não sequencial precisaria usar um [mapa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264887/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado, Maniero... vou consultar suas dicas à medida que for precisando.. quanto a concatenar nomes de variáveis eu já resolvi usando preprocessamento....

Comment: Não deveria fazer isto.

Answer (score -3):

você pode usar a função std::to_string() para converter valores numéricos em strings e, em seguida, usar o operador de concatenação + para unir as strings.

por exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int idade = 25;
    std::string nome = "João";
    
    std::string mensagem = "Olá, " + nome + "! Você tem " + std::to_string(idade) + " anos.";
    std::cout << mensagem << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```